# How to iteratively change variable value until all predicted probabilities are above .5

Tags: r, dplyr, prediction

I am trying to write code that subtracts a given value from a variable until each row has a predicted probability at or above .05.

```
train <- data.frame('cost'= c(120, 3, 2, 4, 10, 110, 200, 43, 1, 51, 22, 14),
                    'price' = c(120, 20, 10, 4, 3, 4, 30, 43, 56, 88, 75, 44),
                    'dich' = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0))

train$dich <- as.factor(train$dich)

test <- data.frame('cost'= c(13, 5, 32, 22, 14, 145, 54, 134, 11, 14, 33, 21),
                   'price' = c(32, 11, 210, 6, 3, 7, 22, 423, 19, 99, 192, 32)
            )

model <- glm(dich ~ cost + price,
             data = train, 
             family = "binomial")

pred  <-   predict(model, test, type = "response")

           1            2            3            4 
3.001821e-01 4.442316e-01 4.507495e-04 6.310900e-01 
           5            6            7            8 
5.995459e-01 9.888085e-01 7.114101e-01 1.606681e-06 
           9           10           11           12 
4.096450e-01 2.590474e-02 9.908167e-04 3.572890e-01
```

So in the above output the cases 4, 5, 6, and 7 would remain the same because they are already above .05 but for the rest of the cases I would like to subtract 1 from the price column and then run the prediction again and repeat until all cases have a probability at or above .05.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to subtract 1 for each row (or "customer") individually, rather than 1 across the board:

```
test$pred_prob <- NA
for (n in 1:nrow(test)) {
  print("-----------------------------")
  print(n)
  while (TRUE) {
    pred <- predict(model, test[n,], type = "response")
    print(pred)
    test$pred_prob[n] <- pred
    if (sum(pred > 0.05) == length(pred)) { 
      print(test$price[n])
      break 
    }
    test$price[n] <- test$price[n] - 1
  }
print(test)
}

# cost price  pred_prob
# 1    13    32 0.30018209
# 2     5    11 0.44423163
# 3    32    96 0.05128337
# 4    22     6 0.63109001
# 5    14     3 0.59954586
# 6   145     7 0.98880854
# 7    54    22 0.71141007
# 8   134   175 0.05074762
# 9    11    19 0.40964501
# 10   14    82 0.05149897
# 11   33    97 0.05081947
# 12   21    32 0.35728897
```

Comment: Oh I noticed the price column has not changed, I would like the new values per row so that I can see what the resulting price should be that pushes the probability over .05. I'm curious why include the   print("-----------------------------")
and
print(n) lines?

Comment: Just a habit for loops so that I can track what I am doing, see how long it will take to run, debug issues etc. It's more helpful if they are really long or slow running. Feel free to remove them.

Comment: Oh gotcha okay I figured also quick question, why do you add 1 at the beginning? test$price <- test$price + 1

Comment: Also disregard the beginning of the first comment I was reading the wrong line. I'll edit when it allows me to

Comment: haha because I fixed the code in a lazy way. Because I subtracted before testing > 0.05 I would have accidentally subtracted 1 from the ones that didn't need it. Here I'll fix it.

Comment: @AidenGawronski I forgot that I need test to be a matrix and not a dataframe. I'm getting an error that the argument is of length 0 and I'm guessing this is the issue. Any advice would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: `test <- as.matrix(test)`

Comment: hey @AidenGawronski thanks for the reply, the prediction I am running is with an xgboost model so I need the loop to work with a matrix rather than a dataframe. Should the loop work for a matrix just as for a dataframe? Maybe there is another issue with the "argument is length of 0" error I am getting. I double checked and the prediction function was working if I ran it just once outside of the for loop.

Comment: I just tried running the example after changing test to a matrix and it says "Error in 1:nrow(test) : argument of length 0"

Comment: Dataframes and matrices behave differently so you should not expect the code to run without adjustment. There isn't enough information here to help you. I would recommend opening a new question if you are still struggling after some effort to revise.

Comment: Sounds good thanks so much for your help, I have training in stats but not programming so this will be a good "learning to fish" experience.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are trying to do but the results are quite hilarious. This is if you want to subtract 1 from all elements of price each time:

```
x <- 1
while (TRUE) {
  print("----------------------------------------")
  print(x)
  test$price <- test$price - 1
  pred <- predict(model, test, type = "response")
  print(pred)
  x <- x + 1
  if (sum(pred > 0.05) == length(pred)) { 
    print(test)
    break 
  }
}
# ... loops 247 times
# [1] "----------------------------------------"
# [1] 248
# 1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9         10         11         12 
# 0.99992994 0.99996240 0.93751936 0.99998243 0.99997993 0.99999966 0.99998781 0.05074762 0.99995669 0.99887117 0.97058913 0.99994594 
# cost price
# 1    13  -216
# 2     5  -237
# 3    32   -38
# 4    22  -242
# 5    14  -245
# 6   145  -241
# 7    54  -226
# 8   134   175
# 9    11  -229
# 10   14  -149
# 11   33   -56
# 12   21  -216
```

Comment: haha yeah well I don't want to subtract 1 from rows where the prediction is already at or above .5 and this is just made up data so I don't expect the results to make much sense. 

Would it make sense to add the pred column to the test df then use subset?

test$price[pred < .05] - 1

Comment: see the other answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else wants to run the same thing with a xgboost model.

```
train <- data.frame('cost'= c(120, 3, 2, 4, 10, 110, 200, 43, 1, 51, 22, 14),
                    'price' = c(120, 20, 10, 4, 3, 4, 30, 43, 56, 88, 75, 44))

label <- data.frame('dich' = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0))

train <- as.matrix(train)

label <- as.matrix(label)

model <- xgboost(data = train,
                 label = label,
                 max.depth = 3, 
                 nround = 1, 
                 objective = "binary:logistic") 

test <- data.frame('cost'= c(13, 5, 32, 22, 14, 145, 54, 134, 11, 14, 33, 21),
                   'price' = c(32, 11, 210, 6, 3, 7, 22, 423, 19, 99, 192, 32)
)

test <- as.matrix(test)

#FOR A MATRIX

test <- cbind(test, rep(NA, nrow(test)))
colnames(test)[3] <- c("pred_prob")

for (n in 1:nrow(test)) {
  print("-----------------------------")
  print(n)
  while (TRUE) {
    pred <- predict(model, t(test[n,]), type = "response")
    print(pred)
    test[,"pred_prob"][n] <- pred
    if (sum(pred > 0.5) == length(pred)) { 
      print(test[,"pred_prob"][n])
      break 
    }
    test[,"price"][n] <- test[,"price"][n] - .01
  }
  print(test)
}
```

It seems to take a while to run on 12 rows. I need to do some thinking about the thresholds of a tree model and how that'll effect a range of different changes in the price to obtain at or above .5 probability (which I meant in my first question but I wrote .05 haha).